# Can't install gulp on my folder

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I already installed `node.js`, `npm` and gulp on my computer (windows 7), but when I'm trying to install gulp on my project's folder with the `"npm update --save-dev"` commande line, I got an error and I don't know how to fix this. But when I do all these steps on my portable (windows 10) it works perfectly...

[image: screen shot of the cmd error]

Here's the log of the error :

> 11930 warn test@1.0.0 No repository field.
>   11931 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename
>   'G:\Desktop\TFA\node_modules\@gulp-sourcemaps\identity-map\node_modules\source-map' -> 'G:\Desktop\TFA\node_modules\@gulp-sourcemaps\identity-map\node_modules.source-map.DELETE'
>   11932 verbose cwd G:\Desktop\TFA
>
> 11933 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
>
> 11934 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program 
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "update" "--save-dev"
>
> 11935 verbose node v9.9.0
>
> 11936 verbose npm  v5.6.0
>
> 11937 error path G:\Desktop\TFA\node_modules\@gulp-sourcemaps\identity-map\node_modules\source-map
>
> 11938 error code ENOENT
>
> 11939 error errno -4058
>
> 11940 error syscall rename
>
> 11941 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'G:\Desktop\TFA\node_modules\@gulp-sourcemaps\identity-map\node_modules\source-map' -> 'G:\Desktop\TFA\node_modules\@gulp-sourcemaps\identity-map\node_modules.source-map.DELETE'
>
> 11942 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>
> 11943 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]

Comment: Have you installed gulp locally with "npm install --save-dev gulp" first?

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [POST Format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Comment: Did you check the permissions of the folder and file?

Comment: @Mark the same error occures when i try the npm install --save-dev gulp..